# SVG markers made in InkScape appear transparent in QGIS

Tags: qgis, svg, markers, inkscape

Using `QGIS 2.14.3` on `Ubuntu 16.04`, I created a custom icon using inkscape for QGIS. You can find it [here](https://github.com/radumas/mbta_station_icons/blob/master/MBTA_bluegreen.svg) (Update: that icon is now fixed). In inkscape, in my filesystem, it displays as:
[image]

However in QGIS, it displays as

[image]

The colors are transparent. How can I fix this?

Comment: Possibly relevant https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118164/svg-issues-in-qgis-api

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see the same issue. Took a look at this file in InkScape, and used <kbd>Shift-Ctrl-F</kbd> to bring up the **Fill and Stroke** properties.

I noticed that the fill on your green and blue areas were set to 'pattern fill', stripes 1:1.

Make a note of your blue and green colours first. Next, change to use **'Flat Color'** on both the coloured areas, then reselect your colours manually.

Save as a new SVG, using "Plain SVG" (to be on the safe side), and you'll find it works...

Go from:-

[image]

to...

[image]

Comment: Nail on the head. I fixed the pattern and was updating the question, but needed to also save it as a `plain svg`